# What is the best way to create pages(about/my home/references tabs) as in the image below?

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I just started learning Android programming. I've created a page and I want to create "About/My Home/References" tabs in the image below.

The "About/My Home/References" tabs (you can see them in the link below) all act like a button. When I click the "About" tab, I can see the things about the users. When I click the "My Home" tab, I can see the some text about my home. The third tab also does the same thing.

Image link:  https://imgyukle.com/i/4LgQH

My question is how can I do this in Android Studio? I've added three button but it doesn't look like that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabLayout` with `TabItems` widgets. Visit, for example, https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/ for short overview and https://www.codingdemos.com/android-tablayout-example-viewpager/ as step-by-step manual.

Answer (score 0):

For that layout, you want to use `Fragments` and a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`.

Your main `Activity` would contain 3 `Fragments`, `AboutFragment`, `HomeFragment` and `ReferencesFragment`.

This would allow you to build each layout separately. The `ViewPager` would contain the `Fragment`, and lets you swipe between them. The `TabLayout` contains your buttons, to tell the `ViewPager` which to show.